# How does one use instance methods in a static method? I'm trying to async'ly create a document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller, i have a method defined as:

```
def self.store_pdf(id)
...
end
```

in that method, I need to call render_to_string to render the correct file / layout:

```
render_to_string(
    :action => "../view/current_version/show.pdf.erb", 
    :layout => false)
```

but because render_to_string is both an instance method and protected, I need to do the following:

```
me = self.new # self is the cortroller
me.send(:render_to_string,
    :action => "../view/current_version/show.pdf.erb", 
    :layout => false)
```

but then there are dependencies such as the response object that render_to_string needs to work, as shown here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string

So, I began adding them

```
me.send(:response=,  ActionController::Response.new)
```

But, more and more of the global instance variables need to be defined, and I decided it was too much work just to try to get one static method to work.

The method needs to be static, so that delayed_job can run the method in the background at a later time.

Anyone have an idea as to how to pull this off?

Comment: Why do you define your method as a class method? What's the reason?

Comment: Because Delayed Job adds a send_later(:action, *args) method to each class. Beleive me, if I could just do, object.send_later, I would, but Delayed Job tells me I can't dump anonymous class, so, the method I use with send_later needs to be static... =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read erb via ERB if you are not using any rails helper,If you are using any rails helper then include Rails helper.
you can refer using [here](http://iparamtech.blogspot.in/2011/09/generate-pdf-using-erb-or-haml-and.html) or

```
require 'erb'
class PdfRender
 #include ActionView::Helpers::OutputSafetyHelper
 #include helper if any is present any
 def self.render_pdf(id)
  #set any instance variable if you are using in pdf 
  content = File.read('path/of/erb/template')
  template = ERB.new(content) 
  # template content will give you text now you can render or generate pdf
  template_content = template.result(binding)


 end
end
```

Note: 
`replace h()` with `CGI.escapeHTML()`

Comment: what is binding?
how does it know what objects to use when rendering the erb?

Comment: binding will bind the variables to scope,http://onestepback.org/index.cgi/Tech/Ruby/RubyBindings.rdoc best guide is ruby object modeling and meta programming http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-dtrubyom/the-ruby-object-model-and-metaprogramming

Comment: If you are using pdfkit you can go through article

Comment: I'm not using pdfkit, I'm using DocRaptor, but I'll play with this, and see what happens.

Comment: My erb has a call to a method in a view helper, which are instance methods, is there a way to get access to those motheds without having to write a static version of the same thing? I also call render a few times, as my views are pretty complex, and require partials.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16366/discussion-between-amar-and-thelindyhop)